# VBA How to find last insert id?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, lastinsertid

I have this code:

```
With shtControleblad
    Dim strsql_basis As String
        strsql_basis = "INSERT INTO is_calculatie (offerte_id) VALUES ('" & Sheets("controleblad").Range("D1").Value & "')"

        rs.Open strsql_basis, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

        Dim last_id As String
        last_id = "select last_insert_id()"
End With
```

The string last_id is not filled. What is wrong? I need to find te last_insert_id so I can use it in an other query.

Comment: last_id does not contain "select last_insert_id()" ? How much do you bet on that ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `rs.movelast` after you open the recordset, that should help

Comment: How would that apply to my situation? And what about when more people are using the db?

Comment: What is it you're really trying to do? You'd like to select the last inserted id, based on an insert statement? Maybe you should run a select statement first, then move to the last record, read from it, and then with that data, do the insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
last_id = "select last_insert_id()"
```

You have set the sql statement to be executed, but have ***not executed it***.
Call `rs.Open` with the above statement to get the 'last_insert_id` instead.

If mysql supports multiple sql statements on single line, you could do

```
strsql_basis = "INSERT INTO is_calculatie (offerte_id)  
VALUES ('" & Sheets("controleblad").Range("D1").Value & "')
; select last_insert_id()"

rs.Open strsql_basis, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: It does not support multiple statements.

I have tried
            Dim last_id As String
            last_id = "select last_insert_id()"

            rs.Open last_id, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

But not the result wanted.